# how to manage uipickerview in uiactionsheet

Tags: ios, uipickerview, uiactionsheet

i am trying to show the UIPickerView in UIActionSheet . from the below mentioned code it works great in portrait mode but looks wired in Landscape Mode. (my app support iPhone 4/5 n landscape orientation also).
    what i am doing wrong ?

```
 actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                              delegate:nil
                                     cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                     otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];


    CGRect pickerFrame=CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0);

    UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    pickerView.dataSource = self;
    pickerView.delegate = self;


    [actionSheet addSubview:pickerView];

    UISegmentedControl *closeButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"OK"]];
    closeButton.momentary = YES;
    closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(260, 7.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f);
    closeButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    closeButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissActionSheet:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [actionSheet addSubview:closeButton];
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
    [actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 485)];
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got the solution

First of all i have to set the width of the picker view as i have mentioned

```
CGRect pickerFrame=CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0);
```

so it can be like

```
CGRect pickerFrame=CGRectMake(0, 40, 320, 0);
```

I found one more good solution :

Just call the picker view in action sheet by clicking a text field:

```
self.textField.inputView = yourCustomView;
```

Comment: i used the third option, is awesome!